# Assigning XML to .Java using java.R

Tags: java, android, xml, netbeans

so i'm working on an android web service app and have a java class called BookDetails.java located in the source packages and an Xml file named info.xml in the layout folder 
but when i implement

```
setContentView(R.layout.info);
```

i get an error saying cannot find symbol

I feel as though im being an idiot not seeing how to fix this.

Comment: <ImageView android:id="@+id/book_picture" like such?

Comment: never mind that comment it appears that you do not have to set the id of the `layout` perhaps it is how you created the activity. Did you try generating the activity through your ide?

Comment: I created it myself, and have the same method working in several other instances. I'm reading through the code now to see if it's any spelling errors

Comment: for some reason netbeans hadn't added info.xml when i created the file so i had to manually add it to the directory

Comment: I'd suggest you move to `Android Studio`

Comment: Check in your activity, the import section, and make sure to be importing the R. file of your app.

Answer (score 0):

R.java might not be generated well (or even prevented from generation) if you have some errors in your code. Remember to refresh or rebuild your project after adding any type of resources.